# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate returns NULL and no error callbacks 2023

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I'm learning Node, Mongo and Mongoose. I have the following:

```
async function addProductToSale (saleId, productId) {
    let result = await saleModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
        saleId,
        { $push: { productos: productId } },
        { new: true },
    );
    console.log(result);
};
```

And of course it's not working. I get NULL values on console (registers are not being updated) and can't find some callback or error variable to debug.

Here's the Schema also

```
const ventaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    autor: String,
    total: Number,
    pago: String,
    productos: [
        {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Productox"
        }
    ],
    fecha: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    publicado: Boolean
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Ventax",ventaSchema);
```

I've tried to find some callback seems it'd got removed. I reviewed logic and options also, Ids are fine, etc. I'm expecting the Ids to get pushed into the Mongo document.

Comment: Could you post the code the creates your model, because you have `mongoose.model("Ventax...)"` but are using `await saleModel.findByIdAndUpdate`?

Comment: I've already have but you mean this maybe: `const saleModel = require("./modelos/ventaModel.js");`

Comment: Thank you. The fact you are getting a `null` on the `console.log(result)` indicates no document was found. I can only assume the `saleId` variable is wrong or you don't have a document with that `_id`. If you `console.log(saleId)` before you perform the `findByIdAndUpdate` you can know for sure. Post the code that calls the `addProductToSale` function.

Comment: Found it! in the call i have the ids the other way around... `await addProductToSale(product_id,sale_id);`

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue make sure the saleId you're passing actually exists in your collection.Ensure you have error handling to capture any potential errors during the  data update.

```
async function addProductToSale(saleId, productId) {
    try {
        let result = await saleModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
            saleId,
            { $push: { productos: productId } },
            { new: true }
        );
        if (!result) {
            console.log('No document found with the provided saleId');
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error updating document:', error);
    }
}
```